# Cannot Install Mono (Depends Errors)

Tags: mono

I cannot install Mono.  I have the PPA added.  After doing 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get upgrade', I then try 'sudo apt-get install mono-complete' and I get this:

```
owner@Linux:~$ sudo apt-get install mono-complete
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: mono-devel (= 4.2.2.30-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-4.0-service (= 4.2.2.30-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 4.2.2.30-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
owner@Linux:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
owner@Linux:~$
```

So nothing is held back.  I even went to Software & Updates and unchecked all the default sources and the ones I added only leaving these three enabled:

```
http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main
http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-apache24-compat main
http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-libjpeg62-compat main
```

Another 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get upgrade', I then try 'sudo apt-get install mono-complete' and get the same error.

Comment: Perhaps the "libgdiplus (Debian 8.0 and later, NOT Ubuntu" message in the install instructions has something to do. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives

Comment: Why are you using Debian PPAs? Are you using Debian?

Comment: Their directions at http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives say to use those PPAs.

Comment: @xangua THANK YOU!  I removed that and all is good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to a comment to my question by **xangua**, I saw I had added a PPA that was not meant for Ubuntu.  If you follow their instructions at http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives, be sure to not accidentally add the **libgdiplus** PPA.

Answer (score -2):

Add the repository for mono extras (do the following as sudo)

```
echo "deb https://d2nlctn12v279m.cloudfront.net/repo/mono/ubuntu bionic main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-extra.list  

apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys CB2DE8E5

apt-get update
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on Ask Ubuntu! What is the PPA you mention? Who does maintain it? Would it be possible to rather use PPA from mono project or Canonical...?

Comment: NEVER USE RANDOM PPA